# Ruby: How to call a macro from a macro?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like a macro that invokes two other macro calls. E.g.,

**Before:**

```rb
  class Apple < ValidatedObject::Base
    attr_accessor :diameter
    validates :diameter, type: Float
  end
```

**After:**

```rb
  class Apple < ValidatedObject::Base
    validates_attr :diameter, type: Float
  end
```

My question is really, how to implement `#validates_attr`, which has no other job but to make the two separate macro calls.

I've been reading up on macros, seeing `define_method`, etc. But if I'm **only** delegating to two other existing macros, do I need to truly write a new macro for that? I've experimented with writing a class method but haven't got it working.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "macro" in Ruby. This is just a "DSL", or "Domain Specific Language" in Ruby parlance.

Comment: You can create a [Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) here that encapsulates this method, then mix it in with an `include`. What you need here is `def validates_attr` inside your `class_methods` block. That method, given arguments, can delegate to the `attr_accessor` and `validates` method as necessary.

Comment: Those are method calls. Might be clearer with parentheses: `attr_accessor(:diameter)` and `validates(:diameter, type: Float)`. Just define a 3rd method that calls the other two. No meta programming needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a method in your `ValidatedObject::Base` class like this:

```
class ValidatedObject::Base
  def self.validates_attr(name, type:)
    attr_accessor name
    validates name, type: type
  end

  #...
end
```

and call that method from your `Apple` subclass like this:

```
class Apple < ValidatedObject::Base
  validates_attr :diameter, type: Float
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a class method, make whatever method calls you need from that method. For example:

```rb
module ValidatedObject
  class Base
    def self.validates name, type:
      puts "will validate #{name} for #{self}"
    end
  end
end

module Attributes
  def attribute name, type: nil
    attr_accessor name
    validates(name, type:) if type
  end
end
  
class Apple < ValidatedObject::Base
  extend Attributes

  attribute :diameter, type: Float # validated attribute
  attribute :color                 # just attribute
end
```